# Macbook Pro stuck on password sign in

Tags: macbook-pro, password

I can't log on to my 2011 MacBook Pro. It boots up ok with the chime, then goes to the Apple logo screen, then to the "enter password" screen. There I'm completely stuck as can't get past the log in screen showing my picture and it asking me to put in the password.

It " shakes its head " when I input the password. After a few experiences of this I reset the password using Apple ID but it still doesn't recognise the new password.  Tried rebooting using Cmd R and also tried Cmd S.

If I reboot with Cmd-R it goes straight to Apple logo page then sign in page and the box for the password fills up with dots as if I were typing in a very long password

Comment: what exactly does not work? is the Mac loading endlessly after login, are you unable to inout your password,...? Also what macOS version and what exact MBP? This question lacks detail, please take the tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The  computer starts fine, then there is the Apple logo, and it moved on to the "enter password" page. I am able to  type in my password when it asks but when I press the return arrow on the screen it "shakes its head " . After a few experiences of this I reset my password using my Apple id but it still doesn't recognise it.  So I am unable to get past the password page . I think I,m on OS 14.3 ( can't get into the  computer to check for sure) . I dont know what MBP means

Comment: MBP is short for MacBook Pro. You can't run iOS on them though :-)

Comment: Also, if you boot with Cmd-R, where do you end up?

Comment: Thank you ! Well whatever the latest update is for a MBP. Cant check as cant get into it.  I always install updates when prompted. It's a late 2011 15"

Comment: If I reboot with Cmd-R it  goes straight to Apple logo page then sign in page and the box for the password fills up with dots as if I were typing in a very long password

Comment: Your last comment makes it sound like one of more keys is stuck down & constantly pressing. That would be time for a repair shop, if we can confirm that.

Comment: That's a useful insight - thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Just to make this into an actual answer…

It seems very likely, after your last comment which I edited into the question body for you, that you have a stuck key which is auto-repeating as you are trying to type.

I think you may need a repair shop.